# how to reverse a string in place without reversing the punctuation? c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to reverse the words in a string without any effect on punctuation.
This is my current code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

string ReverseString(string str, int len)
{
    string trans;

      for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
            trans+=str.substr(len-i-1,1);
      return trans;
} 

int main()
{
    string original;
    string trans;

    cout << "input: ";
    getline(cin,original);


    trans=ReverseString(original,original.size());

    cout << "out: "  ;
    cout<<trans<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Expected behavior:

> input : Welcome to AC, CVB!
>
> Expected output : emocleW ot CA, BVC!

Observed behavior:

> input : Welcome to AC, CVB!
>
> output : !BVC ,CA ot emocleW

Comment: Hint: Use `string::find` to find the next space or punctuation. Afterwards, reverse all characters in between.

Comment: Two steps. First write a string reversal function that accepts start and end iterators. Then feed it pairs of appropriate iterators ;)

Comment: Also, you can use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) to do the actual reversing rather than write the function yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a while loop over words and reverse them instead of the whole line:

```
string word;
while(your_end_condition)
{
  cin >> word; // this takes one word at a time
  cout << ReverseString(word, word.size()) << " ";
}
```

You can make stringstream from you original string if you don't want to use cin

Comment: what about the punctuation? op doesn't wanna change their position

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Those characters will be included into words, so you will get words like "AC," and "CVB!". This will be very easy to put into your string reversing function. Just if last character is a letter - if it isn't, keep it in last position.

Answer (score 0):

What about this way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

void myReplace(std::string& str,
               const std::string& oldStr,
               const std::string& newStr)
{
    std::string::size_type pos = 0u;
    while((pos = str.find(oldStr, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, oldStr.length(), newStr);
        pos += newStr.length();
    }
}

std::string reverWords(const std::string& str)
{
    auto inp{str};
    auto out{str};
    std::regex rgx("[a-zA-Z]+");

    std::smatch res;

    while(regex_search(inp, res, rgx))
    {
        std::string s{res[0]};
        std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        myReplace(out, std::string{res[0]}, s);
        inp = res.suffix();
    }
    return out;
}
int main(int /*argc*/, char* argv[])
{
    std::string str = "Welcome to AC, CVB!";
    std::cout << reverWords(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Regular expressions might be overkill here. Also the current regex will not take numbers.

Comment: @AndyG Well in the example are no numbers. I thing the task is from some school project and most of the programmers are avoiding regex and invents their own wheel.

Comment: Can't say I disagree, but can't say I totally agree either. There are legitimate reasons to avoid regex, the main one being performance (but when it's built into the language like in Perl, you tend to use it all willy-nilly).